# Show my custom post id if a country or ip

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, ip

I explain.
When a user wants to see the country come my website, for example my url: my-post-example.html

I would like to capture the id and display content with the template, etct I have done in another post id, ie show a different post I tell you by id.

I want to do without redirect and also I would like to do so through the file functions.php

**UPDATE:**

Example:

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=="89.0.0.0" && $post->ID==15){

  //No display post with id 15, show the entire post with ID 5 and custom data
}
```

Can it be done?

Thanks!!

Comment: Please elaborate what you want to achieve, as it is unclear from your description. Are you talking about differen posts depending on the visitors country of origin?

Comment: @fischi I have set an example

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do something like this (not tested):

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=="89.0.0.0" && $post->ID==15){

 $post5 = get_post('5');
 echo $post5->post_title;

 //Call custom meta using $post5->ID;

}
```

**Update:** If you'd like to replace the original object you can do the following:

`if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=="89.0.0.0" && $post->ID==15){
    global $post;
    $post = get_post('5');
    setup_postdata($post);
    //Here you can call for the_content() or the_title etc.
    wp_reset_postdata(); //This function will bring back the old post id
}`

Comment: Is it possible to overwrite or replace the object $post?

Comment: I just updated my answer - have a look and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I have complicated, because I also want to leave the title and any meta tag, in addition to the template chosen in this post, and if I do so with file_get_content?

Comment: If you want to keep the title and meta tags of the NEW post, then you need to call if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=="89.0.0.0" && $post->ID==15) way earlier in the header.

Comment: I'm trying to add_action action ('init', 'change_all'); functions.php file in the theme, but the truth does not work very well. Is there any better for this action? The title is replacing me not in the sidebar and in the "last post" always get the same name.